# adding week column based on timedate condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a date column and I need to add a classification for this week's projects and Cumulative.

```
df_site['RECEIVE DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_site['RECEIVE DATE'])
    
# week value
df['Report_Type'] = df_site['RECEIVE DATE'].dt.isocalendar().week
```

The above code works fine and creates week# of receive date

but now I need to check if week number = to today's week# then add weekly else Cumulative

```
df_site["Report_Type"] = np.where(df_site['RECEIVE DATE'].dt.isocalendar().week >=
                                  df_site['RECEIVE DATE'].dt.isocalendar().today, "Weekly","Cumulative")
```

Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to check if week number = to today's week

Since you need today's week number, `df_site['RECEIVE DATE'].dt.isocalendar().today` value is incorrect.

You should get today's week number like this

```
import datetime

week_num = datetime.date.today().isocalendar().week
```

Comment: it works but it keeps considering some dates in Feb as weekly

Comment: oh, your answer is correct. I found that my date conversion is wrong. thanks